Calling a useState hook inside of a declared function causes an error - Violating React Hook rules
I'm trying to write a simple program where I call a useState hook inside of a declared function in a useEffect hook.
Here's my code:
export default function Library() {

    const [libs, setLibs] = useState([{label: "hello", value: "Hello"}])

    useEffect(() => {
        const FuncLibraries = async () => {
            const data = await GetLibraries()

            // Calling setLibs here, which was defined at the top using the useState() hook

            setLibs(data)
        }

        FuncLibraries()
        console.log(libs)
    }, []);

   return (
        <View>
            <Stack.Screen 
            options={
                {
                    headerStyle: styles.HeaderStyle, 
                    headerTitleStyle: styles.HeaderTextStyle, 
                    headerRight:(() => 
                                        <Dropdown
                                                style={styles.libraryDropDownScroll}
                                                itemContainerStyle={styles.libraryDropDownItem}
                                                containerStyle={styles.libraryDropDownContainer}
                                                data={libs}
                                                labelField="label"
                                                valueField="value"
                                                placeholder='Main'
                                                onChange={item => {}}
                                                renderRightIcon={() => (<Ionicons name="arrow-down" size={20} color={Colors.black} style={styles.closeIconStyle}/>)}
                                                />
                                        
                                    )
                    
                    }
                }/>
            </View>
        );
    };


This results in the error:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
Here's the code for GetLibraries:
export default async function GetLibraries () {
    const [libs, setLibs] = useState([]);
    const email = await getItemFor("email");


    useEffect(async () => {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
            .storage
            .from('pdfs')
            .list(`${email}/books`);
        
        if (data != null) {
           const libraries = [];
           for (let x = 0; x < data.length; x ++) {
               libraries.push({label: data[x].name, value: x.toString()})
                };
            
        setLibs(libraries);
    }}, [])

    return(libs)
};


I'd recommend including enough code so we can see it's inside a function component because it doesn't sound like it is given the error message.

What does GetLibraries look like? And what is the complete error message w/ a reference to the source? I don't undertstand the comment that says "calling useState here", (a) you're not, (b) you can't, and (c) not sure why you'd want to.

You've written GetLibraries like a hook, but you're calling it like an otherwise normal function.
If it's meant to be a hook, it should be called just like useState or useEffect (and should be renamed to perhaps useLibraries).  For example:
export default function Library() {

  const libs = useLibraries();

  return (
    /* your JSX code */
  );
}

In fact with that hook there's no need for useState or useEffect within the component because the hook already uses those.
Note also that useLibraries shouldn't be async.  That hook function itself shouldn't await anything.  And its useEffect shouldn't have an async function passed to it.  Follow the same pattern you followed in your component's useEffect to declare an async function if needed and call that function.
For example:
export default function useLibraries () {
  const [libs, setLibs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLibraries = async () => {
      const email = await getItemFor("email");

      const { data, error } = await supabase
        .storage
        .from('pdfs')
        .list(`${email}/books`);
        
      if (data != null) {
        const libraries = [];
        for (let x = 0; x < data.length; x ++) {
          libraries.push({label: data[x].name, value: x.toString()})
        }
            
        setLibs(libraries);
      }
    };

    fetchLibraries();
  }}, [])

  return libs;
};


Alternatively, if you want to manage state/effects in the component and not in their own hook then don't make GetLibraries a hook.  Just make it a function that returns its result:
export default async function GetLibraries () {
    const email = await getItemFor("email");

    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .storage
      .from('pdfs')
      .list(`${email}/books`);
        
    if (data != null) {
      const libraries = [];
      for (let x = 0; x < data.length; x ++) {
        libraries.push({label: data[x].name, value: x.toString()})
      }
            
    return libs;
}

And use that result:
export default function Library() {

  const [libs, setLibs] = useState([{label: "hello", value: "Hello"}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLibraries = async () => {
      const data = await GetLibraries();
      setLibs(data);
    }

    fetchLibraries();
  }, []);

  const libs = useLibraries();

  return (
    /* your JSX code */
  );
}


Just to clarify, there shouldn't be an error even though you're calling setLibs(data) in the fetchLibraries function? That's what I thought the problem was., but maybe it's something else.

@AnirudhKuppili: setLibs isn't a hook, it's a function returned by a hook.  Read the error message carefully, particularly the line of code it refers to.  It indicates you're calling useState improperly.  In the original code in the question you're calling useState inside of GetLibraries, which you are then calling as a normal function.  Either GetLibraries should be a (renamed) hook and should be used like a hook, or it should be a normal function and shouldn't use hooks.
